# Textfields to appear next to each other instead of underneath each other when using a v-for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, vue.js, textarea, vuetify.js

I have a lot of textfields for which I use a v-for loop to get their label from an array of strings. The problem is the textfields appear underneath each other rather than next to each other as I have specified "xs6 md3" (for xsmall to medium screens two textfields next to each other in each row, for medium to xlarge screens 4 textfields next to each other in each row)

This is my code:

```
 .
 .
 <v-container py-0>
          <v-layout wrap row v-for="numberField in numberFields">
            <v-flex xs6 md3>
              <v-text-field
                 :label="numberField"
                 mask="#########"
                 color="blue"
              />
            </v-flex>
 .
 .
 data: () => ({
    numberFields:[
    "option1","option2", ... "option 57"]
 .
 .
```

This is what I get. textfields underneath eachother rather than being placed next to each other until the row is full and then moving to the next row. How do I make them appear as I have specified "xs6 md3"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because you are repeating the layout and not the flex item.

Try something like:

```
<v-layout wrap row>
        <v-flex xs6 md3 v-for="numberField in numberFields">
        ...
        </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Comment: Actually I tried it like the way you mentioned it first, it yields the same result (all textfields underneath each other)

Comment: When I do a small example it is exactly do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/q3Ljv2te/

Comment: actually your first solution works. Sorry my mistake :)

Comment: Cool. Happy coding!